# AS3 Only allow access to certain properties on DisplayObject

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, frameworks

I have a getter within a class which is used to make my property `skin:DisplayObject` **read-only**. This class also has a property `body:AvBody` which is used to define the `x` `y` `width` `height` etc of the object, which in turn positions the `skin`.

What I want to do is disable access to the properties `x` and `y` on `skin` unless accessed from within the `internal` namespace (where `AvBody` is also located) Is this possible?

Note: I **can't** make skin any type other than `DisplayObject` (I can't even make `skin` a class that extends `DisplayObject` because it creates issues with library symbols).

Comment: If I understand well, there's an object A that has both skin and body properties. But the body is the only one that should modify the skin. Am I right ? Then, why is skin a property of the "A" object and not a property of the body ?

Comment: The body probably represents a physics body while the skin is the view/movieclip. Hence if skin was to be a property of body it would create high coupling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't have an individual skin class just put skin into a namespace that only AvBody and AvChild can access.

Comment: Hm, I actually have a namespace already set up for situations like this too.. **facepalm**.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you're running into a design issue here, and you would probably be able to avoid wanting or needing to do this with some restructuring of code.  perhaps you could merge `skin` and `avBody` into one class?  you can decide and for now let's assume that a redesign is not the solution.

unfortunately, since function overloading is not possible in AS3, a solution like the following is also not possible since overrides must have identical signatures:

```
override public function set x(value:Number, caller:*):void
     {
     if     (caller is AvBody)
            super.x = value;
     }

     //Error:  Incompatible override.
```

you could simply override `x` and `y` setters, displaying an `ArgumentError` if they are called, and instead use custom internal setters for the `x` and `y` properties, even though it's kinda ghetto.

```
override public function set x(value:Number):void
     {
     throw new ArgumentError("Can not set public 'x' property on Skin class.  Set internal 'posX' property instead");
     }

override public function set y(value:Number):void
     {
     throw new ArgumentError("Can not set public 'y' property on Skin class.  Set internal 'posY' property instead");
     }

internal function set posX(value:Number):void
     {
     super.x = value;
     }

internal function set posY(value:Number):void
     {
     super.y = value;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know you can't do that. But as [TheDarkIn198](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336929/thedarkin1978) mentioned, you have a design issue that would be good to look at. Instead of merging body and skin, I would suggest implement the body (AvBody) features on the actual class. Or make a new class, called **Body** or something, that every object that have body will inherit from.

But as I know that you are developing a framework, you don't need to limit its use, since the framework will be internal and the user of the framework won't need to have access to **skin**, only for exceptional cases, so you can disable it completely via a namespace. Here I'm hoping you have methods that serves every need that the user may have, for example adding an object to another (inheritance, similar to addChild). You will be amazed to know that some libraries work. [TweenMax](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/&rct=j&q=tweenmax&ei=Q_b5Tf_GFOjz0gHCgPHTAw&usg=AFQjCNGXI2J7WC2rWQehJD4fTei4HRu7gg&sig2=yBh7QP1o5AJG8tVtA0JQbQ&cad=rja), for example, makes every *internal* variable public, but in the comment they put `/** @private **/`.

So, in my opinion, its best to not limit the variable, but to have it well documented.

Comment: They will need access to skin to be able to define graphics - ie skin = new BlockMC(); But maybe I could make skin private alltogether and just have a setGraphics() method within AvChild.